# setTimeout double click issue

Tags: jquery, css

In my table I want to click on a row. When the row is clicked it expands up and down. To show the expanded content I need position relative and a higher z-index for the selected row.

When I click the row again to collapse it, it falls behind the other rows so I need to delay removing the higher z-index and position setting.

I've have played with .delay and that only seems to apply for the animate function not the css function. I tried using queue on the css function but that failed to work also.

The closest I have come to success is the code below, however, for some reason it requires me to double click to collapse the row rather than single click. What have I done wrong? Thank you

```
$( ".expanding" ).toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).animate ({
            'z-index': '9999',
        }, 1)
        $(this).css({ position: 'relative'});
        }, 
        function() {
        $(this) = setTimeout((function() {
            $(this).animate ({
                'z-index': '0',     
            })
            $(this).css({ position: 'static'});
        }), 500);
    });
```

EDIT; Also, I cannot use toggleClass for this section before anyone mentions it.

EDIT2: As @charlietfl pointed out.. " 'this' inside the setTimeout loses context of element".. I reset that and fixed my issue.

Comment: `$(this) = setTimeout(...);` What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net so we could try it ourselves?

Comment: `toggle( Fn, Fn)` is deprecated. What version of jQuery are you using? `this` inside the setTimeout loses context of element

Comment: @Brock To respond to someones comment, type `@` followed by their username so that they'll receive a notification... Otherwise it's unlikely that they'll see your comment..

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm expecting other jquery to run which collapses the expanded divs (working). The expectation of this code is that it would delay for long enough for the divs to collapse before it sets the low z-index and standard position (working). This way while the divs are collapsing they are still presented on top of the other <tr>'s rather than behind them which looks messy. The issue is I have to double click for it work which is really odd. Thanks

Comment: @Brock Couldn't you just provide a minimalistic jsFiddle which replicates your issue? Which jQuery version are you using? Please answer previous questions posted in comments

Comment: @charlietfl That was precisely the issue. 'this inside the setTimeout loses context of element'.. I reset that and fixed my issue. I'm not sure how to set your comment as an answer

Comment: @A.Wolff The issue has been resolved and I have posted an answer thank you so much for trying to assist and I'm sorry I didn't have the fiddle up in time for you

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl pointed out.. " 'this' inside the setTimeout loses context of element".. I reset that and fixed my issue.